# JQuery confirmation dialog after pressing the submit button but before POSTing with .ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a very simple scenario where I want to POST the form using JQuery's ajax() method but perform request some confirmation from the user before actually performing the post.

I have a JQuery UI dialog with localized buttons in place in case you wonder what all the code with buttons below is about.

This is my code so far:

```
var i18n_deleteButtons = {};

i18n_deleteButtons[i18n.dialogs_continue] = function () {
    return true;
    $(this).dialog('close');
};

i18n_deleteButtons[i18n.dialogs_cancel] = function () {
    return false;
    $(this).dialog('close');
};

$('#delete-dialog').dialog({
    open: function () {
        $(this).parents('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(1)').focus();
    },
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 400,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: i18n_deleteButtons
});

$("form#form_attachments").submit(function (event) {
    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();
    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $(this), url = $form.attr('action');

    // build array of IDs to delete (from checked rows)
    var jdata = { 'attachmentIdsToDelete': [] };
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        jdata['attachmentIdsToDelete'].push($(this).val());
    })

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            // Return false if you don't want the form submit. 
            $('#delete-dialog').dialog('open');
        },
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: jdata,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#msg').html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

The dialog actually opens up fine but clicking at any of the buttons results in nothing happening. The post doesn't happen and the dialog does not close regardless of which button was clicked.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Theres way too much fluff going on there.  The core problem has a simple solution.  Simply add a confitmation prmpt which determines whether or not to perform POST on click.  But , u need to first trim this forest of code.

Comment: there's a reason for a fluff here. Localizing the UI dialog requires that it is done this way, no shorter way exists. That's one thing. Another thing is that this way at least we try to separate some concerns as much as possible. Maybe you could post your solution to the core problem but it has to include support for localized dialog confirmation and JSON POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the default jquery UI dialog is a bit cumbersome for regular use and trouble to configure in some custom scenarios I looked around and found this Easy Confirm plugin which is based upon jquery&jquery UI default stuff. It also allows for very simple internationalization.

https://github.com/wiggin/jQuery-Easy-Confirm-Dialog-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Why not move the actual ajax call from the submit handler and trigger it when pushing a button in the delete dialog?

You could store you ajax call in a separat function and pass this functions and the url as parameters to the confirmation routine.

```
 [pseudo code]

 function callAjax() {
     ...
 }
 function submitHandler() {
     confirmDialog({callback:callAjax,param:you_url});
 }
 function confirmDialog(obj) {
     $('#yes_btn').click(function() {
         // call the callback
         obj.callback(obj.param);
     });
     $('#no_btn').click(function() {
        // just close the dialog
     });
 }
```

This way the confirmDialog don't have to know anything about the ajax call, it will just execute the callback with the given parameter when the user clicks ok.

Comment: because logically it's supposed to be in the submit handler. However, if I move it from the submit into the delete dialog button, how do I get the url variable into the dialog?

Comment: This last option looks better but I was instructed and under impression that it is a better practice to attach my code to the .submit() handler for the form.

Comment: I think its impossible to have both the ajax call and your confirmation call in the same handler (if you don't want to use a standard confirmation box).